# turtlebot SCI Problem

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am getting this kind of data when i do rostopic list on my workstation
rex@ubuntu:~$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://turtlebot-laptop:11311

```
rex@ubuntu:~$ rostopic list
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/imu/data
/imu/raw
/joint_states
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/turtlebot_node/parameter_descriptions
/turtlebot_node/parameter_updates
/turtlebot_node/sensor_state
```

And when I try to use the Dash board it says :

Failed to put the turtlebot in full mode: service call failed with error: service [/turtlebot_node/set_operation_mode] responded with an error: error processing request: Robot not connected, SCI not available

And the Minimal launch file output is :

```
rex@ubuntu:~roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
... logging to /home/rex/.ros/log/ad527dac-28bf-11e2-a05f-904ce58884e4/roslaunch-ubuntu-3227.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://192.168.1.101:39972/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /use_sim_time
 * /robot_pose_ekf/sensor_timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/imu_used
 * /robot_pose_ekf/odom_used
 * /robot/name
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/type
 * /turtlebot_node/update_rate
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/timeout
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/path
 * /rosdistro
 * /robot_description
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/base_path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/freq
 * /robot_pose_ekf/publish_tf
 * /app_manager/interface_master
 * /robot_pose_ekf/vo_used
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/path
 * /robot_pose_ekf/output_frame
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/path
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/digital_io/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/mode/startswith
 * /rosversion
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/pub_rate
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/sensors/startswith
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/power/startswith
 * /turtlebot_node/bonus
 * /robot/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/type
 * /diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers/nodes/contains

NODES
  /
    appmaster (app_manager/appmaster)
    app_manager (app_manager/app_manager)
    turtlebot_node (turtlebot_node/turtlebot_node.py)
    turtlebot_laptop_battery (turtlebot_node/laptop_battery.py)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    diagnostic_aggregator (diagnostic_aggregator/aggregator_node)
    robot_pose_ekf (robot_pose_ekf/robot_pose_ekf)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://turtlebot-laptop:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[appmaster-1]: started with pid [3239]
process[app_manager-2]: started with pid [3240]
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [3241]
process[turtlebot_laptop_battery-4]: started with pid [3242]
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [3246]
process[diagnostic_aggregator-6]: started with pid [3256]
process[robot_pose_ekf-7]: started with pid [3257]
turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]
[ WARN] [1352283367.262891124]: The root link base_footprint has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
ERROR: Cannot locate app file for turtlebot_teleop/android_teleop: package is not installed.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.609555] Starting app manager for turtlebot
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.668527] Waiting for foreign master [http://localhost:11312] to come up...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.671613] Foreign master is available
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.762669] Registering (/turtlebot/app_list,http://192.168.1.101:58981/) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.781682] Registering (/turtlebot/application/app_status,http://192.168.1.101:58981/) on master http://localhost:11312
turtlebot_apps.installed
loading installation data for [turtlebot_apps.installed]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.796770] Registering service (/turtlebot/list_apps,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:33609) on master http://localhost:11312
ERROR: Cannot locate app file for turtlebot_teleop/android_teleop: package is not installed.
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.818413] Registering service (/turtlebot/start_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:33609) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283369.833082] Registering service (/turtlebot/stop_app,rosrpc://192.168.1.101:33609) on master http://localhost:11312
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.409820] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.410519] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.410900] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.411544] has gyro: True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.869534] self.gyro_measurement_range 150.000000
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283373.870033] self.gyro_scale_correction 1.000000
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283377.066618] Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer. 

shutdown request: new node registered with same name
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283380.172416] Failed to contact device with error: ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'start']. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/rex/.ros/log/ad527dac-28bf-11e2-a05f-904ce58884e4/turtlebot_node-3*.log
respawning...
[turtlebot_node-3] restarting process
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [3309]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283381.807797] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283381.808558] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283381.809344] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283381.810150] has gyro: True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283382.154787] self.gyro_measurement_range 150.000000
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283382.157791] self.gyro_scale_correction 1.000000
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283385.310458] Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer. 

shutdown request: new node registered with same name
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283388.360061] Failed to contact device with error: ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'start']. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
[turtlebot_node-3] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/rex/.ros/log/ad527dac-28bf-11e2-a05f-904ce58884e4/turtlebot_node-3*.log
respawning...
[turtlebot_node-3] restarting process
process[turtlebot_node-3]: started with pid [3321]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.202477] serial port: /dev/ttyUSB0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.203247] update_rate: 30.0
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.203753] drive mode: twist
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.204228] has gyro: True
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.561660] self.gyro_measurement_range 150.000000
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283389.562596] self.gyro_scale_correction 1.000000
^C[robot_pose_ekf-7] killing on exit
[diagnostic_aggregator-6] killing on exit
[turtlebot_laptop_battery-4] killing on exit
[robot_state_publisher-5] killing on exit
[app_manager-2] killing on exit
[turtlebot_node-3] killing on exit
 [appmaster-1] killing on exit
[INFO] [WallTime: 1352283390.912458] Unregistering (/turtlebot/app_list,http://192.168.1.101:58981/) from master http://localhost:11312
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/core.py", line 462, in signal_shutdown
    h()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/multimaster_experimental/app_manager/src/app_manager/app_manager.py", line 102, in shutdown
    self._api_sync.stop()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/multimaster_experimental/app_manager/src/app_manager/master_sync.py", line 290, in stop
    self.foreign_manager.unsubscribe_all()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/multimaster_experimental/app_manager/src/app_manager/master_sync.py", line 217, in unsubscribe_all
    self.unadvertise(t,u)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/multimaster_experimental/app_manager/src/app_manager/master_sync.py", line 161, in unadvertise
    m.unregisterPublisher(topic,uri)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/tools/rosgraph/src/rosgraph/masterapi.py", line 402, in unregisterPublisher
    return self._succeed(self.handle.unregisterPublisher(self.caller_id, topic, caller_api))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1575, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 951, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 811, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 773, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 754, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283391.321252] Failed to contact device with error: ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'start']. Please check that the Create is powered on and that the connector is plugged into the Create.
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

Please suggest me the solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47647/turtlebot-sci-problem/) by [kunalrex2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3539/kunalrex2010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem comes not from the dashboard. It starts earlier:

`[ERROR] [WallTime: 1352283377.066618] Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0.  Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.`

This means that turtlebot_node.py was never even able to connect to your iRobot device in the first place.
I would suggest you start with a simple

```
rosrun turtlebot_node turtlebot_node.py
```

in order to see clearer what it going wrong. Once you figured that out, continue with the big launch file.
Why turtlebot_node.py actually gets no connection to your iRobot device can have different reasons.

- Does your user have permission to open a serial port?
- On my setup it happens, that I have to replug the serial converter once after rebooting my laptop for god knows what reasons. After that it works like a charm.
- Are there probably more serial-usb devices on your system and /dev/ttyUSB0 is already occupied?

A good starting point might be to manually connect to serial port and see if that works.

Good luck. :)

---

Originally posted by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) with karma: 237 on 2012-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-12-10**:
Hi. I have a query. I installed the turtlebot package as per the wiki but I am missing the turtlebot_node (and turtlebot_driver) too. Any idea what to do?

**Comment by [JBuesch](https://answers.ros.org/users/1539/jbuesch/) on 2013-12-10**:
Please open a new question for that. This is a Q&A platform and not a forum. Nobody will find your question in this post. And from what you wrote I have no idea at all. When you put a new question, please provide as much information as you can do in order to relieve people from guessing.  :)